# django i18n - template translation but language specific

Tags: django

I need to translate `"ago"` in `"3 hours ago"`

I am using `|timesince` which gives me `"3 hours"` in all languages. so I only need to translate the word `"ago"`.

```
{{updated|timesince}}
```

BUT:

this thing will be in german: `vor 3 Stunden` which has the word `"vor"`(en. "ago") in the first place.

how can I get language specific translation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#de.po
msgid "%s ago"
msgstr "vor %s"

{% blocktrans with param=updated|timesince %}
    {{ param }} ago
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to write you own filter that has the behavior you want.

Won't need to modify much of the timesince code though:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/731f313d604a6cc141f36d8a1ba9a75790c70154/django/utils/timesince.py#L10

Comment: django has named strings for translation in views, but not in templates. this really hurts